# jQuery UI resizable changes height when resizing width

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have a very simple DIV element that I'm trying to resize and drag horizontally. It works fine but the height of the DIV element is also changed by jQuery UI. I don't understand why.

Anyone an idea?

JS code:

```
$('.task')
    .draggable({
        axis: 'x'
    })
    .resizable({
        containment: 'parent',
        handles: 'e, w'
    });
```

HTML code:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="task status-green">
      <span class="handle-move"></span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS code:

```
li {
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

.task {
  height: 16px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  position: relative;
}

.task span {
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}

.task .handle-move {
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: move;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 0;
  z-index:1;
}

.task .ui-resizable-handle {
  background-color: pink;
  cursor: e-resize;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
}

.task .ui-resizable-w {
  left: 0;
}

.task .ui-resizable-e {
  right: 0;
}

.status-green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, resizable-function fails trying to manage the "box-sizing" css-property. Try using

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

or make an inner container for the padding.